# Doctrine (Symfony) How to setup filtered indexes

Tags: symfony, doctrine

is it possible to define in Doctrine (Symfony) with attributes filtered indexes for mysql?

My goal is to have only one value in the table that is allowed to be TRUE. If one is set to TRUE, all others must be FALSE.

In MySql I would do it like this:

```
create table test
(
    id int primary key,
    foo bool
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX only_one_row_with_column_true_uix 
ON test((CASE WHEN foo = true THEN foo END));

insert into test values (1, false);
insert into test values (2, true);
insert into test values (3, false);
insert into test values (4, false);
insert into test values (5, true);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/nO2Zak2f

Or is there a better way to do this with validators or anything other?

Comment: I'm not an expert but I think you should be to create a manager or a controller in order to do that.

Comment: I solved this with Symfony validators. Thank you.